# EnqueueBundle , google pub sub transport

Tags: interop, google-cloud-pubsub, symfony5, producer, enqueue

i use enqueue Bundle with google pub sub in symfony 5, bellow the config[enqueue configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggT51.png)

and when i send a command to queue i have this error

[pub sub error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/szOxX.png)

please any solution?

thx.

i put in proscessor

```
public static function getSubscribedCommand()
{
    return[
        'command' => 'validation',
        'processor' => 'validation',
        'queue' => 'validation',
        'prefix_queue' => true,
        'exclusive' => true,
    ];
   
}
```

and

- '@enqueue.client.default.spool_producer' as a producer